# Adding a new column to a dataframe with a value which is based on the values from next rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe as shown below,

```
+-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+
|jobid|fieldmname|new_value|coltype|           createat|
+-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+
|    1|  jobstage|  sttaus1|   null|2022-10-10 12:11:34|
|    1| jobstatus|  sttaus2| status|2022-10-10 13:11:34|
|    1|  jobstage|  sttaus3|   null|2022-10-10 14:11:34|
|    1| jobstatus|  sttaus4|   null|2022-10-10 15:11:34|
|    1| jobstatus| sttaus10| status|2022-10-10 16:11:34|
|    1| jobstatus| sttaus11|   null|2022-10-10 17:11:34|
|    2|  jobstage|  sttaus1|   null|2022-10-11 10:11:34|
|    2| jobstatus|  sttaus2| status|2022-11-11 12:11:34|
+-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+

  Seq(
(1, "jobstage", "sttaus1", "null", "2022-10-10 12:11:34"),
(1, "jobstatus", "sttaus2", "status", "2022-10-10 13:11:34"),
(1, "jobstage", "sttaus3", "null", "2022-10-10 14:11:34"),
(1, "jobstatus", "sttaus4", "null", "2022-10-10 15:11:34"),
(1, "jobstatus", "sttaus10", "status", "2022-10-10 16:11:34"),
(1, "jobstatus", "sttaus11", null, "2022-10-10 17:11:34"),
(2, "jobstage", "sttaus1", "null", "2022-10-11 10:11:34"),
(2, "jobstatus", "sttaus2", "status", "2022-11-10 12:11:34")
).toDF("jobid", "fieldmname", "new_value", "coltype", "createat")
```

Need to add new column and add value only for rows where fieldmname is "jobstage".
and the value should be latest status (check in next rows) for that corresponding jobstage. while selecting latest need to check for coltype value if it's "status".

Expected dataframe:

```
+-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------+
|jobid|fieldmname|new_value|coltype|           createat|latest_status|
+-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------+
|    1|  jobstage|  sttaus1|   null|2022-10-10 12:11:34|      sttaus2|
|    1| jobstatus|  sttaus2| status|2022-10-10 13:11:34|             |
|    1|  jobstage|  sttaus3|   null|2022-10-10 14:11:34|     sttaus10|
|    1| jobstatus|  sttaus4|   null|2022-10-10 15:11:34|             |
|    1| jobstatus| sttaus10| status|2022-10-10 16:11:34|             |
|    1| jobstatus| sttaus11|   null|2022-10-10 17:11:34|             |
|    2|  jobstage|  sttaus1|   null|2022-10-11 10:11:34|      sttaus2|
|    2| jobstatus|  sttaus2| status|2022-11-11 12:11:34|             |
+-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+-------------+
```

I tried with lead, lag, row_number  but not getting expected result.

Comment: Can you please clearly elaborate the conditions you are mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is tagged [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark), so I'm writing a way to do the required in pyspark using the `first()` window function.

```python
data_sdf. \
withColumn('latest',
           func.when(func.col('fieldmname') == 'jobstage', 
                     func.first(func.when((func.col('coltype') == 'status') & (func.col('fieldmname') == 'jobstatus'), func.col('new_value')), ignorenulls=True).
                     over(wd.partitionBy('jobid').orderBy('createat').rowsBetween(0, sys.maxsize))
                     ).
           otherwise(func.lit(''))
           ). \
show()

# +-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+--------+
# |jobid|fieldmname|new_value|coltype|           createat|  latest|
# +-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+--------+
# |    1|  jobstage|  sttaus1|   null|2022-10-10 12:11:34| sttaus2|
# |    1| jobstatus|  sttaus2| status|2022-10-10 13:11:34|        |
# |    1|  jobstage|  sttaus3|   null|2022-10-10 14:11:34|sttaus10|
# |    1| jobstatus|  sttaus4|   null|2022-10-10 15:11:34|        |
# |    1| jobstatus| sttaus10| status|2022-10-10 16:11:34|        |
# |    1| jobstatus| sttaus11|   null|2022-10-10 17:11:34|        |
# |    2|  jobstage|  sttaus1|   null|2022-10-11 10:11:34| sttaus2|
# |    2| jobstatus|  sttaus2| status|2022-11-10 12:11:34|        |
# +-----+----------+---------+-------+-------------------+--------+
```

So, it will consider the first record from the corresponding records where `fieldmname` is "jobstatus" and `coltype` is "status".

Comment: Thanks a lot. One issue is there -  1|  jobstage|  sttaus3|   null|2022-10-10 14:11:34| --->  this row should have sttaus10 value. but next row has status10 in your output dataframe, please check,